# How to use as.hexmode width

Tags: r, hex

According to the R documentation:

```
as.hexmode(x)

## S3 method for class 'hexmode'
as.character(x, ...)

## S3 method for class 'hexmode'
format(x, width = NULL, upper.case = FALSE, ...)

## S3 method for class 'hexmode'
print(x, ...)
```

> Arguments
>
> x  An object, for the methods inheriting from class "hexmode".
>
> width  NULL or a positive integer specifying the minimum field width
>   to be used, with padding by leading zeroes.

If I call in R 3.02:

```
> hex <- "5"
> as.hexmode(hex,width=2)
```

I get the error:

```
Error in as.hexmode(hex, width = 2) : unused argument (width = 2)
```

How do I call as.hexmode correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `width` parameter belongs to `format` (well, `format.hexmode`), not `as.hexmode`:

```
format(as.hexmode(hex), width=2)
```